# How to generate squares (randomly located, equally sized, randomly rotated) that don't intersect each other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been working on generating a layer of randomly rotated and placed squares on a 1x1 grid. I have been able to generate a single square that is randomly placed and rotated on the grid, but I'm not sure how to improve the code to generate more random squares that do not intersect with each other. Current code seen below:

[Example of my One Randomized Square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIrh.png)

```
from math import cos, pi, sin
from random import randint
from matplotlib.mlab import frange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, axis, show

def flake_position_layer1(): #Determines the initial position of one corner of the square
    x0 = randint(0, 100) / 100
    y0 = randint(0, 100) / 100
    theta = randint(0, 90) * pi / 180 #Angle of rotation for the square
    return x0, y0, theta


def flake_shape(): #generates the other 3 corners of the square
    x0, y0, z, theta = flake_position_layer1()
    x1 = x0 + (0.1 * cos(theta))
    x2 = x1 + (0.1 * cos((90 * pi/180) + theta))
    x3 = x2 + (0.1 * cos((180 * pi/180) + theta))
    y1 = y0 + (0.1 * sin(theta))
    y2 = y1 + (0.1 * sin((90 * pi/180) + theta))
    y3 = y2 + (0.1 * sin((180 * pi/180) + theta))
    return x0, x1, x2, x3, y0, y1, y2, y3


def display(): #connects the 4 corners on a plot
    x0, x1, x2, x3, y0, y1, y2, y3 = flake_shape()
    return plot([x0, x1, x2, x3, x0], [y0, y1, y2, y3, y0])


display()
axis([0,1,0,1]) #1x1 grid
show()
```

I do not have a CS background (I'm an environmental engineering major) and I am extremely inexperienced with coding. Please give me any recommendations that you may have for me to try and tackle this problem with!

Comment: Is it possible to consider a circular enveloppe around the square ? In such case you can save the center of each squares and verify that distance between both center is > 2*z.

Comment: Use rejection sampling to generate more squares: 
`if(current square overlaps) reject(); else add_square_to_list();`

Comment: How large do the squares need to be? If you can make them less than ~70% (1/√2) the grid size, they'll never overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Math background

#### 1. Algebra

- 1<sup>st</sup> degree function (or [[Wikipedia]: Linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function)) is a **function** ([[Wikipedia]: function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))) whose:

  - Expression can be written as: `f(x) = a * x + b` (***a*** and ***b*** constants, ***x*** variable)
  - Graphical representation is a straight line in the *xOy* plane ([[Wikipedia]: Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system))

#### 2. Plane Geometry

- A plane consists of an (infinite) number of points: let's refer to a point by its coordinates which can be referred to as:

  - *abscissa* or *horizontal coordinate* or (simply) *x*
  - *ordinate* or *vertical coordinate* or (simply) *y*
- The points in the plane spread across 2 dimensions
- In the plane, every point can be uniquely identified by its *x* and *y*
- Some of the points in the plane might have some common characteristics: e.g. a bunch of points that are on a straight line... a point that is on a straight line satisfies the line straight line **equation** (which is an expression generally defined as *${**function** (from previous paragraph) result} = ${value}*)
- So, in short: for a point *P<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)*, if `y0 == f(x0)`, the point **is** located on **that** straight line (and **more**: depending on **y<sub>0</sub>** being **greater** / *lower* than *f(x<sub>0</sub>)*, ***P<sub>0</sub>*** is located **above** / *below* the straight line in the *xOy* plane). Again, I want to state that for non linear functions, `y = f(x)` still applies (as it's the general equation formula), but other operators (e.g. ***<***, ***>***) don't

  - **! Important Note !**: everything discussed here applies to a variety of functions (don't want to say **all**), but I'm limiting to *linear functions*, for clarity's sake
- A straight line is determined by 2 **distinct** points (e.g. *P<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)*, *P<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>))* - the equation for that straight line would be `y = a * x + b` (in our example: `y = ((y0 - y1) / (x0 - x1)) * x + (y0 - x0 * ((y0 - y1) / (x0 - x1)))`); **!!** Of course it worth mentioning the "vertical" (parallel to *Oy*) line which is **!! not a function !!**
- Example: having 2 **distinct** parallel (non *Bolyai* :) ) lines: `f0(x) = a * x + b0` and `f1(x) = a * x + b1` (***a*** is the same for both lines - this is the condition for them to be parallel) and an external point *P<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>)* (that obviously doesn't belong to any of the lines). How to determine if *P<sub>0</sub>* is between the 2 lines? Well, the point must be above (the lower) one and below the other (the higher one). Translated into math (considering *f<sub>0</sub>* being the lower one):

  - `y0 > f0(x0)` (`y0 - f0(x0) > 0`)
  - `y0 < f1(x0)` (`y0 - f1(x0) < 0`)

  From the above observations (and there may be more wisdom), this is the condition that the point coordinates should satisfy: `(y0 - f0(x0)) * (y0 - f1(x0)) < 0`
- ***Going further***: a square consists of 2 sets of parallel lines (its sides); if a point is between each lines pair, then the point is in the square.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from random import random, seed
from math import pi, sin, cos, sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi_2 = pi / 2

MINX = MINY = 0
MAXX = MAXY = 1
DEFAULT_SIDE = 0.1
DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN = DEFAULT_SIDE * sqrt(2)
MAX_SQUARES = 30

__global_generation_counter = 0


def get_func_deg1(p0, p1):
    (x0, y0), (x1, y1) = p0, p1
    if x0 == x1:
        return None
    a = (y0 - y1)/(x0 - x1)
    b = y0 - x0 * a
    return lambda x: a * x + b


def is_point_in_square(p, sq):
    x, y = p
    p0, p1, p2, p3 = sq
    side_func0 = get_func_deg1(p0, p1)
    side_func1 = get_func_deg1(p1, p2)
    side_func2 = get_func_deg1(p2, p3)
    side_func3 = get_func_deg1(p3, p0)
    if not side_func0 or not side_func1 or not side_func2 or not side_func3:
        xmin = min(p0[0], p2[0])
        xmax = max(p0[0], p2[0])
        ymin = min(p0[1], p2[1])
        ymax = max(p0[1], p2[1])
        return xmin <= x <= xmax and ymin <= y <= ymax
    return ((y - side_func0(x)) * (y - side_func2(x))) <= 0 and \
           ((y - side_func1(x)) * (y - side_func3(x))) <= 0


def squares_overlap(square0, square1):
    for p0 in square0:
        if is_point_in_square(p0, square1):
            return True
    for p1 in square1:
        if is_point_in_square(p1, square0):
            return True
    xc0 = (square0[0][0] + square0[2][0]) / 2
    yc0 = (square0[0][1] + square0[2][1]) / 2
    if is_point_in_square((xc0, yc0), square1):
        return True
    # The "reverse center check" not needed, since squares are congruent
    """
    xc1 = (square1[0][0] + square1[2][0]) / 2
    yc1 = (square1[0][1] + square1[2][1]) / 2
    if is_point_in_square((xc1, yc1), square0):
        return True
    """
    return False


def __generation_monitor():
    global __global_generation_counter
    __global_generation_counter += 1


def generate_random_point(minx=MINX, miny=MINY, maxx=MAXX, maxy=MAXY, safety_margin=DEFAULT_SAFETY_MARGIN):
    if maxx - minx < 2 * safety_margin or maxy - miny < 2 * safety_margin:
        print("MUEEE")
        safety_margin = 0
    x = safety_margin + random() * (maxx - minx - 2 * safety_margin)
    y = safety_margin + random() * (maxy - miny - 2 * safety_margin)
    __generation_monitor()
    return x, y


def generate_random_angle(max_val=pi_2):
    return random() * max_val


def generate_random_square(side=DEFAULT_SIDE, squares_to_avoid=()):
    while 1:
        restart = False
        x0, y0 = generate_random_point()

        angle = generate_random_angle()
        x1 = x0 + side * cos(angle)
        y1 = y0 + side * sin(angle)

        angle += pi_2
        x2 = x1 + side * cos(angle)
        y2 = y1 + side * sin(angle)

        angle += pi_2
        x3 = x2 + side * cos(angle)
        y3 = y2 + side * sin(angle)

        ret = (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)
        for square in squares_to_avoid:
            if squares_overlap(ret, square):
                restart = True
        if restart:
            continue
        return ret


def square_to_plot(square):
    xs, ys = zip(square[0], square[1], square[2], square[3])
    return xs + (xs[0],), ys + (ys[0],)


def main():
    seed()
    squares = list()
    allow_overlapping = False # CHANGE to True to allow square to overlap
    for _ in range(MAX_SQUARES):
        #print("Generating:", _)
        if allow_overlapping:
            square = generate_random_square()
        else:
            square = generate_random_square(squares_to_avoid=squares)
        squares.append(square)
    plot_squares = tuple()
    for sq in squares:
        plot_squares += square_to_plot(sq)
    print("STATS:\n    Squares: {}\n    Allow  overlapping: {}\n    Generated values: {}".format(MAX_SQUARES, allow_overlapping, __global_generation_counter))
    plt.plot(*plot_squares)
    plt.axis([MINX, MAXX, MINY, MAXY])
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I didn't work with *matplotlib* before (actually, I `pip install`ed it for this task)
- General comments:

  - A point is represented by a tuple representing its coordinates: *(x, y)*
  - A square is a tuple consisting of 4 points *(p0, p1, p2, p3)*
- *get_func_deg1*:

  - Returns the function that describes the line that contains the 2 points given as arguments
  - If the 2 points are on a line that is parallel to *Oy* (there's no "normal" function to describe it), simply return *None*
- *is_point_in_square*:

  - Determines if a point is inside a square
  - Uses the logic explained above, except
  - For the special case when the square edges are parallel to *Ox* and *Oy* when it uses some simple arithmetic operations
- *squares_overlap*:

  - Determines whether 2 squares overlap (I'm sure there are faster "algorithms")
  - Checks if any of the 1<sup>st</sup> square corners are inside the 2<sup>nd</sup> one
  - The other way around: checks if any of the 2<sup>nd</sup> square corners are inside the 1<sup>st</sup> one
  - Since the above 2 checks are not enough (imagine a regular [[Wikipedia]: Octagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagon) and unifying its vertices every 2<sup>nd</sup> one: there will be 2 squares neither having its corners in the other one, but sharing their "central" areas), also check that one square's center is inside the other one
- *generate_random_point*:

  - Generates a point in the given bounding box
  - *safety_margin* specifies the (minimum) distance that the generated point should be away from any of the bounding box sides, in order that any square that will have this point as a corner, would fit entirely in the bounding box
- *generate_random_angle*:

  - Generates a random angle between 0 and (*π* / 2)
- *generate_random_square*:

  - Generates a random point, a random angle, and constructs a square starting from there, using the specified side
  - *squares_to_avoid* is a list of squares. After the square is generated, it is checked against every square from that list. If the 2 squares overlap, the square is regenerated
- *square_to_plot*:

  - Converts a square (from a tuple of points) to *matplotlib* format (2 tuples consisting of *x*s and *y*s with the 1<sup>st</sup> element duplicated as the last)
- *main*:

  - The main function
- *__generation_monitor* <sup>**(0)**</sup>:

  - Internal function used for profiling
- In order to change the number of squares, modify *MAX_SQUARES*

**Output**:

[image: Draw window]

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q046081491]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> STATS:
>     Squares: 30
>     Allow  overlapping: False
>     Generated values: 1135
> ```

---

Few words about the squares generation

- As seen in the output, for 30 displayed squares, *1135* were generated (at this run). That is because they were overlapping
- If changing from *main* `allow_overlapping = True`, *Generated values* in the output will match the number of squares (*MAX_SQUARES*)
- If increasing *MAX_SQUARES* to values let's say higher than *50*, the number of generated values will increase exponentially (so will the time needed to generate them), and the chance that the program will enter an infinite loop (because it won't be able to generate a square that doesn't overlap to another one) will grow as well

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here is what I've come up with with a little help from the [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) package.  Installation help is at the bottom here.  The ultimate result:

[image]
[image]

#### Code walkthrough

- `distance` is a helper function using the `Point` class from shapely to find the distance between two coordinates.  Just a helper function for later.
- `Square` instantiations a new polygon.  It has 4 corners, each an (x,y) pair, one coordinate for its center, and a scalar value equal to half the distance of its diagonal.
- `test_overlap` is pretty self explanatory by title.  But logically what it does is this: find the distance from center-to-center between the two shapes.  Then find the sum of the half-diagonal of each shape.  If the center-to-center distance is greater than the sum, the squares *cannot* overlap.
- `Squares` starts out with an empty container (empty list) and attempts to add squares to it.  But for each possible new addition, it firsts tests that there is no overlap with existing squares.

#### Code

```
import math
import random

from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point


def distance(a, b):
    return Point(a).distance(Point(b))


class Square(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x0, self.y0 = random.random(), random.random()
        theta = random.randint(0, 90) * math.pi / 180  # Angle of rotation
        self.x1 = self.x0 + (0.1 * math.cos(theta))
        self.x2 = self.x1 + (0.1 * math.cos((90 * math.pi/180) + theta))
        self.x3 = self.x2 + (0.1 * math.cos((180 * math.pi/180) + theta))
        self.y1 = self.y0 + (0.1 * math.sin(theta))
        self.y2 = self.y1 + (0.1 * math.sin((90 * math.pi/180) + theta))
        self.y3 = self.y2 + (0.1 * math.sin((180 * math.pi/180) + theta))
        self.corners = ((self.x0, self.y0), (self.x1, self.y1), 
                        (self.x2, self.y2), (self.x3, self.y3))

    @property
    def center(self):
        """(x, y) of the center of the polygon."""
        return Polygon(self.corners).centroid.coords[0]

    @property
    def half_diag(self):
        """The distance of 1/2 the shape's diagonal (center-to-corner)."""
        p0, p1, p2, p3 = self.corners
        return 0.5 * distance(p0, p1) * math.sqrt(2)


def test_overlap(square1, square2):
    """Do two shapes overlap?  

    Note this is a 'conservative' test.  May return True if they do not
    (false positive), but will never return False if they do (false negative).
    """

    # Distance between two centers
    ctc = distance(square1.center, square2.center)
    # Sum of half-diagonals
    halfdiags = square1.half_diag + square2.half_diag
    res = ctc < halfdiags
    return res


class Squares(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.squares = []

    def add_square(self):
        new_square = Square()
        if not self.squares:
            # Initial empty list/container - just add without any tests
            self.squares.append(new_square)
        else:
            while True:
            # Test that new_square overlaps with existing
                res = [test_overlap(square, new_square) for square in self.squares]
                if any(res):
                    # We have at least 1 case of overlap (1 True)
                    new_square = Square()
                else:
                    # Safe to add
                    self.squares.append(new_square)
                    break

    def plot_squares(self):
        for square in self.squares:
            (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = square.corners
            plt.plot([x0, x1, x2, x3, x0], [y0, y1, y2, y3, y0])
```

#### Example

```
import itertools
%matplotlib inline
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 10):
    # Add 10 squares; you could also just build this into the class
    sqs.add_square()
sqs.plot_squares()
```

[image]

#### Installing `shapely`

Install the Anaconda distribution if you don't already.    Then just use `conda-forge` to install shapely.  From `cmd` run:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install shapely
```

#### Glaring deficiency

At a certain point, your container of squares gets filled up and there is minimal room left to add new shapes.  Even if there is available space, the function is basically trial-and-error, so will take long at high shape counts.  That happens at around 20-25 squares (in a 1.0x1.0 box) at the moment.

Comment: For simplicity and use of existing packages, this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function to determine whether two cube intersect.

```
from math import cos, pi, sin
from random import random
from matplotlib.mlab import frange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, axis, show,axes

LEN = 0.1


def rotate(point, theta):
    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]
    x_ = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta)
    y_ = - x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
    return x_, y_


class CUBE(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, theta):
        self.corner = [(LEN / 2, LEN / 2),
                       (-LEN / 2, LEN / 2),
                       (-LEN / 2, -LEN / 2),
                       (LEN / 2, -LEN / 2)
                       ]
        self.theta = theta
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        for i in range(4):
            self.corner[i] = rotate(self.corner[i], theta)
            self.corner[i] = (self.corner[i][0] + x,
                              self.corner[i][1] + y)


def is_include(cube, point):
    point = [point[0] - cube.x, point[1] - cube.y]
    point = rotate(point, -cube.theta)
    if (point[0] < -LEN / 2
            or point[0] > LEN / 2
            or point[1] < -LEN / 2
            or point[1] > LEN / 2
            ):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def is_intersect(cube1, cube2):
    if (any([is_include(cube1, point) for point in cube2.corner])
            or any([is_include(cube2, point) for point in cube1.corner])
            or is_include(cube1, (cube2.x, cube2.y))):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def plot_cube(cube,n):
    plot(
        [cube.corner[i][0] for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]],
        [cube.corner[i][1] for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]])
    ax = axes()
    ax.text(cube.x,cube.y,str(n))


def display(cubelist):  # connects the 4 corners on a plot
    for i,cube in enumerate(cubelist):
        plot_cube(cube,i)
    axis([0, 1, 0, 1])  # 1x1 grid
    show()


cubelist = []

for i in range(100):
    x0 = random()
    y0 = random()
    theta = random() * pi
    cube = CUBE(x0, y0, theta)
    if any(is_intersect(cube,cb) for cb in cubelist):
        continue
    else:

        cubelist.append(cube)

display(cubelist)
```